# XSS vulnerability in display message

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I have a webpage in which Email is given as input. It will then display "your email is abc@xyz.com". I am then changing the email in URL to <script>alert(1)</script> and send tbe request again. The system now displays "your email is <script>alert(1)</script>". Only the display message is like this. Script doesn't seem to get executed. 
Is this XSS vulnerability or just email validation issue?

Comment: If the script doesn't get executed maybe the payload is not good..maybe this is not an XSS issue, how's your DOM arranged ?

Comment: It is a third party website and I am testing it. Not sure about DOM. Will check that.

Comment: inspect it as html if possible , it might just be html encoded so its safe to display

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons the script is not being executed:

- It is being blocked by a browser filter or a CSP. If this is the case, it would not be displayed on the page, but it would be part of the source code.
- The fake email is properly encoded. If this is the case, you would see it as e.g. `&gt;script&lt;` in the source but `<script>` in the page.
- It is being inserted into the DOM with JavaScript using a safe method like `textContent`.

In general, if you see the payload on the page it is a sign that the filtering is working as it should. If you see it unencoded in the source, it is a sign that you have found an XSS vulnerability. In any case, you are correct that the site in question needs better email validation.